# Как отправить обновленные данные из контроллера Angular?

Tags: angularjs

Добрый день!
Есть массив примерно такого содержания, получаемый с бэкэнда

```
[
  { 'first': 1 },
  { 'second': 2,
  { 'third': 3 }
]
```

Вывожу его не страницу

```
<div ng-repeat="d in ctrl.data">
    <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in d">
        {{key}}
        <input ng-model="value"/>
    </div>
</div>
<button ng-click="ctrl.updateData()">zhmyak</button>
```

Получаю вывод в виде текст - инпут со значением.
Дальше я хочу исправить значение в инпуте и отправить обратно в бэкэнд

Контроллер выглядит так:

```
function myController(apiResource) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.data = [];
    vm.updateData = updateData;
    getData();

    function getData() {
        return apiResource.stats.get().$promise.then(
            function (data) {
                vm.data = data['stats']
            }
        )
    }

    function updateData() {
        return apiResource.stats.put(
            {stats: vm.data}
        )
    }
}
```

При исправлении значения в инпуте и попытке отправить назад - отправляются первоначальные значения (не исправленные).
Как заставить отправлять обновленные данные?

Answer (score 1):

У каждого элемента `ng-repeat` свой скоуп, поэтому нельзя просто так биндить к полю. Следует обеспечить, чтобы первым действием было чтение подполя:

```
<input ng-model="d[key]" />
```